# Still confused by d3's enter method

Tags: d3.js

The trigger for this question is the following snippet of code by `d3.js`'s author ([context](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/time-series-chart.js)):

```
      // Select the svg element, if it exists.
      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

      // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
      var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
      gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "area");
      gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "line");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
```

What throws me off are the comments, especially the "Otherwise" in the second one.

More specifically, the wording of these comments suggests to me that the snippet above would be *equivalent* to the following:

```
    var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

    if (svg.length == 0 || svg[0] === undefined) {
        // svg element does not yet exist
        var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
        gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "area");
        gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "line");
        gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
    }
```

...or maybe even to the following:

```
    var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg");

    if (svg.length == 0 || svg[0] === undefined) {
        // svg element does not yet exist
        var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
        gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "area");
        gEnter.append("path").attr("class", "line");
        gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
    }
    else {
        // svg element already exists
        svg.data([data]);
    }
```

Is any one or the other of these two apparent equivalences actually correct?

If not, what do the four lines of code after the second comment (`// Otherwise...`) do when the `svg` element *does* already exist?

Comment: I'm a relative D3 newbie.  As many times as I've used `enter` and `data`, debugged my use, reminded myself how they work, etc., I find that it's difficult to understand, for sure, how exactly they will interact in all situations, without checking.  So I repeatedly check books, the API docs, whatever I find on the web, `console.log()`, etc.  It's just not a part of me--yet.  This question, with @LarsKotthoff's answer, clarifies `enter` and `data` more than anything I've seen.  I'm printing it and putting it up on my refrigerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are misleading on their own and you have to consider them in their context. Specifically, `.data()` is passed a single-element array, i.e. will only ever match a single element. The whole construct is just a shortcut for doing what's mentioned in the comments -- check if an element exists and if not, create it.

What happens is the following. The code selects all SVGs and matches a single datum to them (`data`). So if there is an SVG already, it will be in the update selection and the enter selection will be empty. If not, the enter selection will have a single element. This is what the "otherwise" refers to -- the "else" is implicit because only the enter selection is handled.

The code, in this specific context, is equivalent to both of the snippets you've posted. It's just shorter.